# onkeypress changeImage

Tags: javascript, image, preload, onkeypress

I have this preloadimages function:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function preloadimages(arr){
var newimages=[], loadedimages=0
var postaction=function(){}
var arr=(typeof arr!="object")? [arr] : arr
function imageloadpost(){
    loadedimages++
    if (loadedimages==arr.length){
        postaction(newimages)
    }
}
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    newimages[i]=new Image()
    newimages[i].src=arr[i]
    newimages[i].onload=function(){
        imageloadpost()
    }
    newimages[i].onerror=function(){
        imageloadpost()
    }
}
return { //return blank object with done() method
    done:function(f){
        postaction=f || postaction 
    }
}
}

preloadimages(['images/image1.jpg','images/image2.jpg','images/image3.jpg']).done(function(images){ 

})
</script>
```

**this is the changeIm function:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeIm(event){
var code;

if(window.event){ 
code = event.keyCode;
}

else{ 
code = event.which;
}   

if (code == 49 || code == 97) {
document.getElementById('imageChange').src='image1.jpg';
}
else if (code == 50 || code == 98) {
document.getElementById('imageChange').src='image2.jpg';
}
else {
document.getElementById('imageChange').src='image3.jpg'; 
}
}
</script>
```

`

```
<body>
<form method="post">
<input size="30" type="text" onkeypress="return changeIm(event)" />
</form>

<img src="images/defaultImage.jpg" id="imageChange" alt="Image" />
</body>
```

Why doesn't work? Also i tried:

```
document.getElementById('imageChange').images[0].src="image1.jpg"; 
document.getElementById('imageChange').images[0];
```

It is work only ones, but i change something and i don't remember now. 
I use this function to change images from keyboard with onkeypress event. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

```
 preloadimages(['images/image1.jpg','images/image2.jpg','images/image3.jpg']
```

According to your `preloadimages` method, the images are located within a directory `images/`

However, in your `changeIm` method, you're doing this:

```
document.getElementById('imageChange').src = 'image3.jpg'; // (missing directory)
// Solution: prefix your URLs with "images/":
document.getElementById('imageChange').src = 'images/image3.jpg';
```

While we're at it, use jQuery to easy implement a cross-browser event handling method:

```
function changeIm(event) {
    var code = event.which
      , image
      , directory = 'images/';

    if (code == 49 || code == 97) {
        image = 'image1.jpg';
    } else if (code == 50 || code == 98) {
        iamge = 'image2.jpg';
    } else {
        image = 'image3.jpg';
    }
    $('#imageChange').attr('src', directory + image);
}
$('#changeImgInput').keypress(changeIm);

<input size="30" type="text" id="changeImgInput" />
```

Comment: You have right to this, but i want to pull images from preload function and not from the server. That's why i use only the name of the image. If i use the root directory in changeIm function i don't need the preload function.

Comment: @f1delak1 The browser should properly cache the images. If you load the same image 10x in your document, the browser should request the file only once (unless your headers say otherwise).

Comment: Because i don't understand a lot. The preload function it is used or not, if i use the root path of the image?

Comment: You have pre-loaded images from `images/image1.jpg`, etc. In your current function, you're trying to load images from `image1.png`, which is a **different path**. Since your current method does not work, I assume that the files do not exist at `image1.jpg`. Therefore, you have to prefix the images with `images/`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just need to prefix the changed images with "images/", ex.

```
document.getElementById('imageChange').src='images/image2.jpg';
```